# ListView inside of stack causing issues in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, listview

**I will be sure to accept the correct answer to this question**
Hello,
I am trying to create  a layout similar to this one
[image: Example Layout]

My plan was to create a column with two expanded widgets, one with a flex of five and the other with a flex of five so that they both take half of the available space, inside the first expanded, I added a background Image, and a Stack widget. Inside the Stack widget, I put 2 text widgets and a listview, I wrapped the listview in a container and set it a height to avoid an unbounded constraint. Then I wrapped the listview inside a positioned widget and tried to nudge it below. I can position the widget later but all I care about is for the listview to be horizontal and overflow the parent container slightly, but nothing shows up when I run the given code.
Here is all the code under **main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email == null
      ? FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.phoneNumber
      : FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.email;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '1268',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        fontSize: 60,
                        fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Points Available',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      //TODO: Mess with this to make the listview overflow its parent container
                       top: 100,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 44,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListView(
                          children: [],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(35),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

```
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
```

Under the pubspec.yaml and import the package in the main.dart

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

This is all you need to reproduce the error, you should see that nothing shows up, I am not sure why and I would love to finally be able to reproduce this layout

Comment: You need to provide width of listView container. Don't use infinite width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the ListView, but with Positioned.

Add left: 0 and right: 0 values to it.

```
  Positioned (
       left: 0,
       right: 0,
       top: 100,
      child: ...
)
```

In this case, do not forget to explicitly specify the width of the child widget. For example: width: double.infinity,

Another option:
you can only add left: 0 to Positioned and not add right: 0, but then Positioned itself or its child widget must have a fixed width. For example: width: 200

Comment: When I do this and try to change the top, it will move accros and get automatically clipped inside of the expanded its in

Comment: Could you visualize the actual result and desired result?

Comment: p.s. If I understand you correctly, you need to move the red Container inside the Stack